# How to navigate to a different view that is not a child?

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native and new to iOS (not programming) so please excuse me if this question is a simple one. I am trying to navigate from one view to another (with a transition), however they are not related so I do not need the back navigation. I actually do not have a navigation bar at all. When using the Navigator component it seems to not support this at all. I am not sure if there is a separate way to do this but I am not able to figure it out without implementing my own hack.

If I use the navigator component and keep pushing on the views then it just keeps them all in memory and I do not want that. I can transition from one view to another and then pop but I may end up going to the wrong view in that case. I can also replace the view but it seems that does not allow for transitions.

To give you a scenario think of it like this:

1. Application starts and loads a "Loading" screen.
2. When initial loading is complete it will then go to the "Login" screen.
3. There is a button on the "Login" screen to "Register" or "Retrieve Password".
4. If they click "Register" it will take them there with a button back to "Login".
5. If they click "Retrieve Password" it will take them to a page with buttons to go back to "Login" or "Register".

So by this example you can see that there is no way to pop because if you were on the login screen and went to the register screen and then wanted to go the retrieve password screen then pop just simply wouldn't work. I do not want any navigation controls on the screen I just want to be able to do a smooth transition between these screens.

Now I was able to find a way to do this but I had to add a method to the Navigator class and hack code in using some of there core methods which seems like its not a good idea at all but here is the code (note this is really just a hack to see if it would work):

```
Navigator.prototype.pushWithUnmount = function(route) {
    var activeLength = this.state.presentedIndex + 1;
    var activeStack = this.state.routeStack.slice(0, activeLength);
    var activeAnimationConfigStack = this.state.sceneConfigStack.slice(0, activeLength);
    var nextStack = activeStack.concat([route]);
    var destIndex = nextStack.length - 1;
    var nextAnimationConfigStack = activeAnimationConfigStack.concat([
      this.props.configureScene(route),
    ]);
    this._emitWillFocus(nextStack[destIndex]);
    this.setState({
      routeStack: nextStack,
      sceneConfigStack: nextAnimationConfigStack,
    }, () => {
        this._enableScene(destIndex);
        this._transitionTo(
            destIndex,
            null, // default velocity
            null, // no spring jumping
            () => {

                this.replaceAtIndex(nextStack[destIndex], 0);
                this.setState({
                    presentedIndex: 0,
                });
            }
        );
    });
}
```

By using the code provided above I am now able to do:

```
this.props.navigator.pushWithUnmount({ component: SomeComponent });
```

With this code the views are pushed onto the stack with a transition and the old views are unmounted when its finished.

Please tell me that I am doing something wrong and that there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Hey, I am also wondering how we can open New screen which not child of any Navigator in android. Did you get any solution on this?

Answer (score 0):

The default router with React Native is pretty limited. I'd check out [React Native Router Flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux). We just switched to it a few weeks ago in our product and have really liked it. It does exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I checked out the project that you linked but I am still running into the problem of accumulating views. I switched my project to use that module but after clicking around a few pages the views just continue to stack up. Not sure if I am missing something but it seems that it does not dispose of the views either when you leave them.

Comment: Also, I just looked at there example project again to see why one might not notice it in there. The reason is that no matter where you go from the main view it always calls "pop". That is not the case with mine all the time.